# electron readonly array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, electron, readonly

I'm using [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) to test some code.
In `app.js`, I create a new array like this:

```
mainWindow.test = [];
```

Next, in `test.js`, I access the current BrowserWindow instance:

```
const currentwindows = remote.getCurrentWindow();
require('run.js');
```

In the required `run.js` file, I want to modify the `test` array I previously created.

```
currentwindows.test.push(1);
```

But somehow the array stays empty, as I also tried in the debugging console:

```
currentwindows.test
[]
currentwindows.test[0] = 'test';
"test"
currentwindows.test[0]
undefined
currentwindows.test = ['test'];
["test"]
currentwindows.test[0]
"test"
currentwindows.test
["test"]
currentwindows.test[0] = 'tutu';
"tutu"
currentwindows.test
["test"]
```

At thhis point, the array behaves like it was readonly, but I also tried this:

```
currentwindows.stackexemple
undefined
currentwindows.stackexemple = []
[]
currentwindows.stackexemple.push('test1');
1
currentwindows.stackexemple;
["test1"]
```

Why do these commands work?
Is this a scope problem?
Or how do I force an array to be read-only in JavaScript?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you get if you type `currentwindows.test` in the console first (before the other entries)?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I get this :  
`> current.windows.test  ` 

`< []`

Comment: Ok after talking with JoWie from #javascript channel on freenode irc.
We thinking that's because the array was copied over IPC.

Like this : 
Note: Arrays and Buffers are copied over IPC when accessed via the remote module. Modifying them in the renderer process does not modify them in the main process and vice versa.

Here : https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md#remote-objects

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out.